# How to convert DataTime Value in specific Culture with c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

i have a DateTime value = `3/24/2011 6:25:29 PM` saved i public DateTime propertie `LastChange`
how can i convert it in German Datetime Form??
like: `3/24/2011 18:25:29`?

Comment: Is it always to be formatted in this way?  Or will you ever need to format it differently for different users (according to each user's culture)?

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
date.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use ToString and specify your custom format string like below

```
LastChange.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a CultureInfo as a IFormatProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute your culture

```
    System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;

    System.Console.WriteLine(now);

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = 
             new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1031); // de-DE
    System.Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(culture));
```